# Maven system scope causes other dependencies to be ignored

Tags: java, maven

I altered my pom.xml file to add a system scoped dependency to a common library which I use as a dependency in multiple projects.  Before adding the system scope dependency, I was able to compile and install the common library and all of it's dependencies would be available in projects which included the common library as a dependency.  After adding the system scope dependency, none of the common library's other dependencies were available within sub-projects.

common library pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.conceptualsystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.9.3</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gnu.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2pre2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/RXTXcomm.jar</systemPath>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Projects which depend on this library should have all of its dependencies available to it.  If I remove the `gnu.io.rxtx` dependency at the end, the other dependencies are available in subprojects.  Why would the behavior change so eratically simply by including a .jar dependency from a local directory?

Desired behavior: Keep original behavior and include new dependency in addition to other dependencies to be available in dependent projects.

Comment: Why using "system" scope? Install that dependency in your repository manager or install it locallaly and use as a usual dependency....

Comment: If the dependency system scoped has other dependencies you have to provide an approriate pom file which contains the information about dependencies... etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise I want the jar to be in `${project.basedir}/lib/` so it can be included in the Git commit along with the rest of the project.  This library is only available in .jar file form and isn't available from mavencentral.

Comment: What you might can create is a jar-with-dependencies or creating via maven-shade-plugin ... apart from that committing a jar into git is a bad idea in particular for reusing... Central is not always an option I know, but you might offer your own repository manager which provides that for customers...(if it shouldn't be public)...

Answer (score 0):

For a normal dependency, maven has access to

- The pom which points to any child dependencies
- The jar file with the binary class files

There's also other artifacts such as

- Javadocs
- Sources
- Checksums

Eg: See the artifacts available for the `spring-core` dependency [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.13/)

When you have a dependency from a `<systemPath>` maven does not have access to the pom or any of the other artifacts. It only has a reference to the the jar so cannot import any child dependencies.